# WCF + MSMQ 4 : Who moves a message from retry queue back to the application queue?

Tags: wcf, msmq, msmq-wcf

This is a simple question, but I was not able to find an answer.

Suppose my message is placed to the retry queue (who creates the retry queue? Is it a WCF or a MSMQ service?)

After 5 minutes (that's my retry delay) that message gets back to the application queue.

Question: who moves a message from retry queue to the application queue after the timeout?

Bonus question: how the delay is being tracked? Does a message get a "moved" timestamp and "retry" timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article [Handling Poison Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703179%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSMQ 4 provides few new features that **allow** an application to handle poison messages using subqueues. These features are:

- abort counter
- move counter
- ability to move messages between main queue and subqueues, as well as between subqueues.

So it seems like actual move is handled by WCF, not MSMQ; and MSMQ simply now has facilities to support poison messages and retries handling.

Answer (score 2):

WCF with MSMQ 4.0 does provides for [automatic retry and poison message handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395218.aspx) although Hugh's answer is correct for older versions of MSMQ.

**Edit from comments:**
On identifying the process that moves messages to the retry queues and back, I'd assume that its the MSMQ service itself since this is a new feature in MSMQ 4.0. WCF participates in the transaction that wraps all this activity and of course, handles messages place in the queue by MSMQ.

Comment: Thanks for that - I wasn't aware of this new feature.

Comment: My client has been using it for over a year in a high volume eCommerce setting and its rock-solid. Saved their biscuits a time or two :)

Comment: I've seen that article, I am not clear though about "message is moved to a retry queue" - who is doing that? since retry parameters are defined on WCF binding, it feels like WCF (i.e. web service) is responsible for that, but at the same time retry is a feature of the MSMQ 4. That's where I am confused at.

Comment: I don't know anything about the internals of moving messages to a retry queue but I'd guess that WCF is not involved in that process other than defining the re-try parameters. Since this is a new feature in MSMQ 4.0 then I'd assume all the message moving is done internally by MSMQ. WCF would be affected the transaction wrapping this processing and in "re-processing" of the message when it gets back in the regular queue.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable reasoning. Please put it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

WCF with the standard msmq bindings (*netMsmqBinding* and *msmqIntegrationBinding*) do not support retries. So in answer to your questions:

*who creates the retry queue?* - You do.

*who moves a message from retry queue to the application queue after the timeout?* - You do.

*how the delay is being tracked?* - You have to do it.

[NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com) is open source and can use MSMQ for transport. This product provides retry functionality out of the box, but does not use WCF.

**UPDATE**

Above is valid for For MSMQ 3 and below.